# rand code via PHP not working online

Tags: php, mysql, database, random

PHP code:

```
$code=rand(1000000000,9000000000);

$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `form` (`code`,date) VALUES ('$code',now())");
```

This code works locally but not online. All code save to database is: 2147483647. How to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the type of your field from **int** to **bigint**

Check this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html

(11.1.4.1. Integer Types (Exact Value))

Int    is between **-2147483648** AND   **2147483647**

BigInt is between **-9223372036854775808** AND **9223372036854775807**

Answer (score 1):

```
2147483647 = 2^31 − 1
```

this is the last integer which can be represented by mysql.
I think you should change the type to 'bigint' and everything will be fine.